# Output JSON array from Query | NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, sql-server

**I'm using Angular and NodeJS to create a chart (ngx-d3-line), I'm pulling the information from a NodeJS API and the query result is the following**

```
`[
    {
        "1": 15147,
        "2": 37079,
        "3": 28077,
        "4": 20281,
        "5": 18246,
        "name": "DEV--ACCEPTED"
    },
    {
        "1": 7,
        "2": 36,
        "3": 30,
        "4": 21,
        "5": 164,
        "name": "DEV--WAITING"
    },
    {
        "1": 6765,
        "2": 20423,
        "3": 14842,
        "4": 10339,
        "name": "DEV--REJECTED"
    }
]`
```

**But the output that I'm looking for is**

```
`[{name: 'DEV-REJECTED',
      series: [
        {
          name: '1',
          value: 6765,
        },
        {
          name: '2',
          value: 20423,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'DEV--WAITING',
      series: [
        {
          name: '1',
          value: 7,
        },
        {
          name: '2',
          value: 36,
        },{
          name: '3',
          value: 30,
        },
      ],
    }
   }]`
```

**Any ideas on how to get that output?**

Comment: Are you in control of the API?

Comment: Yes I can modify the query and get different output

Comment: What about `res.json([your object])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const finalData = data.map(entry => {
    return {
        name: entry.name,
        series: Object.keys(entry).filter(key => key !== "name").map(key => {
            // Filtered out the entries where the key is 'name'
            return {
                name: key,
                value: entry[key],
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify you json through this

```
const final_result =[]; // final out put
data.forEach( v => { // iterate your data
  let d = {series: []}; // decorate your object;
  d.name = v.name;
  delete v.name; // delete name as assigned in other object
  for (let k in v){ // iterate your object
    d.series.push({name:k, value:v[k]});
  }
  final_result.push(d);
});
```

Comment: Consider upvoting the answers that solved your problem.